# VirtualBox: How to sync host and guest time?

Tags: virtualbox

The time in my guest VM is faster than the host time by about 20-30 minutes. What can can I do so that the time in the guest is the same as on the host?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For a Linux host, first install the DKMS (Dynamic Kernel Module Support) package on the guest machine ([source](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp53088720)):

```
$ sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Then install Guest Additions into guest system:

**Ubuntu 20.04+**

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

**Ubuntu 18.04 or older**

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions
```

Also, here are descriptions of [some commands to tune VirtualBox time synchronization](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#fine-tune-timers).

Comment: On recent distributions, you will change those packages for `virtualbox-guest-dkms` and `virtualbox-guest-utils`.

Comment: `apt` is a package manager specifically for Debian-based distributions. This will not work on other Linux guests.

Answer (score 40):

The following setup allows my guest to reliably maintain a time that is accurate to within 1 second of my host. It is tested with the host running VirtualBox 4.3.26 and the guest running the same version of VirtualBox Guest Additions. As for VirtualBox 5.x, I haven't thus far had any need to make these configuration changes; the time has automatically been in sync.

Reference: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changetimesync

---

On the host, list VMs to ascertain the name of the relevant VM.

```
$ VBoxManage list vms | awk '{print $1}'
"CentOS6"
```

---

On the host, configure time synchronization parameters for the guest by running the commands below. First set `$VMNAME` with its appropriate value. If the value of `$VMNAME` contains a space, it should of course be quoted.

```
$ VBoxManage guestproperty set ${VMNAME} "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-interval" 10000
$ VBoxManage guestproperty set ${VMNAME} "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-min-adjust" 100
$ VBoxManage guestproperty set ${VMNAME} "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-on-restore" 1
$ VBoxManage guestproperty set ${VMNAME} "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-threshold" 1000
```

The values of the time parameters above have been constrained to multiples of 10. It may be tempting to set `timesync-set-threshold` to 10000 instead, but this can risk a rather drastic time change when it's triggered, and may therefore break applications.

---

On the host, view the updated relevant values for the guest. These can be reconfirmed at any time.

```
$ VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate ${VMNAME} | grep timesync | sort
Name: /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-interval, value: 10000, timestamp: 1402110397618554000, flags:
Name: /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-min-adjust, value: 100, timestamp: 1402110777505446000, flags:
Name: /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-on-restore, value: 1, timestamp: 1402110904964050000, flags:
Name: /VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-threshold, value: 1000, timestamp: 1402110660162295000, flags:
```

---

On the guest, stop and disable all internal NTP and related timekeeping services. They should not be used as they are likely to interfere with VirtualBox. On a CentOS 6 guest:

```
$ sudo /sbin/chkconfig ntpd off
$ /sbin/chkconfig --list | grep ntp
ntpd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
ntpdate         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

---

On the guest, restart the service named `vboxadd-service`. Assuming Guest Additions was previously installed, this service would have been installed and enabled. On a CentOS 6 guest:

```
$ /sbin/service vboxadd-service status
Checking for VBoxService ...running
$ sudo /sbin/service vboxadd-service restart
Stopping VirtualBox Guest Addition service                 [  OK  ]
Starting VirtualBox Guest Addition service                 [  OK  ]
$ /sbin/service vboxadd-service status
Checking for VBoxService ...running
```

---

If the time on the guest is not yet synced, reboot the guest.

Comment: Thanks!  The final step of restarting the `vboxadd-service` service is what got things working for me, and doesn't seem to be documented (at least at the link you gave).

Comment: When I try this on a CentOS 7  guest,  vboxadd-service is not found? This is a minimal install, no GUI.

Answer (score 2):

I give an other solution to sync time between guest & host without installing Virtualbox guest addition :

1. Install NTP on your guest, and de-comment these lines in `/etc/ntp.conf`.

```
disable auth
broadcastclient
```

2. Activate broadcast on your host. For linux users, edit your `/etc/ntp.conf` file and configure the line

```
broadcast 192.168.123.255
```

For Windows users, activate the “Windows Time” service. You can then [read this page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/04865e36-d43d-4167-a07d-9f28fd4f22fa/how-do-you-configure-windows-time-synchronization-in-a-workgroup-with-no-servers?forum=winserverDS) to configure it to broadcast time

Comment: What's significant about IP address 192.168.123.255?